# Как в джанго передать в шаблон параметр, который можно было бы подставить в тег "URL"?

Tags: python, html, django

.В шаблоне имеется следующий код:

```py
    <a class="nav-link" href= {% url 'organisations_add %} >
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы наименование url - адреса, в теге "url" передавалось из контроллера.
Я попробовал решить это таким способом, но он не сработал:

```py
    context['adding_obj'] = format_html('<a class="nav-link" href={} >',
        mark_safe("{% url 'organisations_add' %}"),
    )
```

Comment: гениально! домен ru.stackoverflow.com, меню на русском, вопросы и ответы на русском, но я все равно напишу свой вопрос по-английски, чтобы нарушить правила сайта.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, что - то я действительно тупанул.